# STM32 NUCLEO programming problem with STLink V2 Clone

Tags: stm32, debugging, keil, st-link, st

Having a trouble with STLink programmer. Error occours in Keil. When I am trying the download code to flash this error appears. If I am using a USB port for debug there is no error. But I need to debug with STLink. I tried to check STLink pins If pins are wrong in the case from the board soldering. But they are correct. I download driver for STlink and Update the firmware too. I connect the required pins (SWDIO, SWCLK power pins) to CUBEMX pins and I guess pins are correct too. When using a ST-LINK Utility another error appears.
I can't figure problem.

[image: ST-LINK Utility error]

[image: Keil error]

---

I don't understand the reason but when I put top of the board side CN2 jumper. I can debug. I am trying to understand reason of it via PCB schematic. When I put that jumper, SWCLK connect with embedded STLink of the Nucleo Board T_JTCK pin. Does this action triggers something?
My wirings and jumper:

[image]

Comment: You can check this video on how to solve this error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEz0C2bT2M0

Comment: @liaifat85 How do you know that watching this video solves the problem?

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: @MSB - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more info, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, then unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you have solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please *don't* use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add clarification or more info, please [edit] the question (unless that would invalidate an answer). || Please see the [tour] & [help]. TY